Single GPU Passthrough on 24.04: nothing happens when starting VM
i am fairly new to all this and trying to set up a VM with single GPU Passthrough. My host is running Ubuntu 24.04 and I'm trying to set up a Windows 11 VM in Virt-Manager.
I've been mostly following the tutorial by SomeOrdinaryGamers on Youtube combined with a few guides to adapt it to Ubuntu.
I have successfully installed Win11 in a VM, and set up all the hooks, however whenever i try to boot the VM after setting up the hooks, nothing happens at all (no error message, no window appearing and immediately reappearing and no Monitors going black). However, the next time i try to reboot or shut down my host machine, instead of shutting down it first throws me into the login screen for my user (if i log in, it presents me with my desktop and no programs open). After a few seconds, no matter if i log in or not, it goes to the typical ubuntu shutting down screen, and the fails to actually shut down. It just goes into a black screen and then i have to hit the reset button on my case.
One attempt, my machine would not boot afterwards anymore (just show me a screen of all the started services with an OK next to them) and i had to reinstall Ubuntu (not an issue - fresh install anyways)
When i run the Start script on its own, it successfully disconnects my Monitor.
I am also not opposed to attempting it with Windows 10 if that works better instead, however id rather not spend another 6 Hours waiting for Windows to install in the VM just for the same outcome.
My PC has a Ryzen 9 3900X and a RTX 3080 plus 32GB of RAM and im installing Windows in a 3TB Partition on a separate Harddrive.
My Scripts currently are as follows:
/etc/libvirt/hooks/kvm.conf
VIRSH_GPU_VIDEO=pci_0000_09_00_0
VIRSH_GPU_AUDIO=pci_0000_09_00_1 

/etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Author: SharkWipf
#
# Copy this file to /etc/libvirt/hooks, make sure it's called "qemu".
# After this file is installed, restart libvirt.
# From now on, you can easily add per-guest qemu hooks.
# Add your hooks in /etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu.d/vm_name/hook_name/state_name.
# For a list of available hooks, please refer to https://www.libvirt.org/hooks.html
#

GUEST_NAME="$1"
HOOK_NAME="$2"
STATE_NAME="$3"
MISC="${@:4}"

BASEDIR="$(dirname $0)"

HOOKPATH="$BASEDIR/qemu.d/$GUEST_NAME/$HOOK_NAME/$STATE_NAME"

set -e # If a script exits with an error, we should as well.

# check if it's a non-empty executable file
if [ -f "$HOOKPATH" ] && [ -s "$HOOKPATH" ] && [ -x "$HOOKPATH" ]; then
    eval \"$HOOKPATH\" "$@"
elif [ -d "$HOOKPATH" ]; then
    while read file; do
        # check for null string
        if [ ! -z "$file" ]; then
          eval \"$file\" "$@"
        fi
    done <<< "$(find -L "$HOOKPATH" -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable -print;)"
fi

/etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu.d/win11/prepare/begin/start.sh
#!/bin/bash
# Helpful to read output when debugging
set -x

# load variables
source "/etc/libvirt/hooks/kvm.conf"

# Stop display manager
systemctl stop display-manager.service
# Uncomment the following line if you use GDM
killall gdm-x-session

# Unbind VTconsoles
echo 0 > /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon0/bind
echo 0 > /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon1/bind

# Unbind EFI-Framebuffer
echo efi-framebuffer.0 > /sys/bus/platform/drivers/efi-framebuffer/unbind

# Avoid a Race condition by waiting 2 seconds. This can be calibrated to be shorter or longer if required for your system
sleep 5

# Unload Nvidia
modprobe -r nvidia_drm
modprobe -r nvidia_modeset
modprobe -r drm_kms_helper
modprobe -r nvidia
modprobe -r i2c_nvidia_gpu
modprobe -r drm
modprobe -r nvidia_uvm

# Unbind the GPU from display driver
virsh nodedev-detach $VIRSH_GPU_VIDEO
virsh nodedev-detach $VIRSH_GPU_AUDIO

# Load VFIO Kernel Module
# not sure if these are with a - or an _ since i found both in different guides, so i tried using both
modprobe vfio
modprobe vfio-pci 
modprobe vfio_pci
modprobe vfio_iommu_type1
modprobe vfio-iommu-type1

/etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu.d/win11/release/end/revert.sh
#!/bin/bash
set -x

# Load variables
source "/etc/libvirt/hooks/kvm.conf"

# Attach GPU devices to host
# Use your GPU and HDMI Audio PCI host device
virsh nodedev-reattach $VIRSH_GPU_VIDEO
virsh nodedev-reattach $VIRSH_GPU_AUDIO

# Unload vfio module
# not sure if these are with a - or an _ since i found both in different guides, so i tried using both
modprobe -r vfio
modprobe -r vfio-pci
modprobe -r vfio_pci
modprobe -r vfio-iommu-type1
modprobe -r vfio_iommu_type1

# Load AMD kernel module
#modprobe amdgpu

# Rebind framebuffer to host
echo "efi-framebuffer.0" > /sys/bus/platform/drivers/efi-framebuffer/bind

# Load NVIDIA kernel modules
modprobe nvidia_drm
modprobe nvidia_modeset
modprobe nvidia_uvm
modprobe nvidia
modprobe drm
modprobe drm_kms_helper

# Bind VTconsoles: might not be needed
echo 1 > /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon0/bind
echo 1 > /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon1/bind

# Restart Display Manager
systemctl start display-manager

and finally my XML in virt-manager:
<domain type="kvm">
  <name>win11</name>
  <uuid>d2bfd573-8485-43c9-88a8-957bfdfe88aa</uuid>
  <metadata>
    <libosinfo:libosinfo xmlns:libosinfo="http://libosinfo.org/xmlns/libvirt/domain/1.0">
      <libosinfo:os id="http://microsoft.com/win/11"/>
    </libosinfo:libosinfo>
  </metadata>
  <memory unit="KiB">28672000</memory>
  <currentMemory unit="KiB">28672000</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement="static">20</vcpu>
  <os firmware="efi">
    <type arch="x86_64" machine="pc-q35-8.2">hvm</type>
    <firmware>
      <feature enabled="yes" name="enrolled-keys"/>
      <feature enabled="yes" name="secure-boot"/>
    </firmware>
    <loader readonly="yes" secure="yes" type="pflash">/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE_4M.ms.fd</loader>
    <nvram template="/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_VARS_4M.ms.fd">/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/win11_VARS.fd</nvram>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <hyperv mode="custom">
      <relaxed state="on"/>
      <vapic state="on"/>
      <spinlocks state="on" retries="8191"/>
      <vendor_id state="on" value="buttplug"/>
    </hyperv>
    <kvm>
      <hidden state="on"/>
    </kvm>
    <vmport state="off"/>
    <smm state="on"/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode="host-passthrough" check="none" migratable="on">
    <topology sockets="1" dies="1" cores="10" threads="2"/>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset="localtime">
    <timer name="rtc" tickpolicy="catchup"/>
    <timer name="pit" tickpolicy="delay"/>
    <timer name="hpet" present="no"/>
    <timer name="hypervclock" present="yes"/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled="no"/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled="no"/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type="file" device="disk">
      <driver name="qemu" type="raw"/>
      <source file="/mnt/06a918ae-9833-4158-866d-f49b6587c64f/win11.img"/>
      <target dev="sda" bus="sata"/>
      <boot order="1"/>
      <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="0"/>
    </disk>
    <disk type="file" device="cdrom">
      <driver name="qemu" type="raw"/>
      <source file="/mnt/06a918ae-9833-4158-866d-f49b6587c64f/Win11_23H2_English_x64v2.iso"/>
      <target dev="sdb" bus="sata"/>
      <readonly/>
      <boot order="2"/>
      <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="1"/>
    </disk>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="qemu-xhci" ports="15">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x02" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="0" model="pcie-root"/>
    <controller type="pci" index="1" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="1" port="0x10"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x0" multifunction="on"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="2" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="2" port="0x11"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x1"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="3" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="3" port="0x12"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x2"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="4" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="4" port="0x13"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x3"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="5" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="5" port="0x14"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x4"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="6" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="6" port="0x15"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x5"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="7" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="7" port="0x16"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x6"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="8" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="8" port="0x17"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x7"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="9" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="9" port="0x18"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x0" multifunction="on"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="10" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="10" port="0x19"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x1"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="11" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="11" port="0x1a"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x2"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="12" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="12" port="0x1b"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x3"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="13" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="13" port="0x1c"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x4"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="14" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="14" port="0x1d"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x5"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="sata" index="0">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x1f" function="0x2"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="virtio-serial" index="0">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x03" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </controller>
    <interface type="network">
      <mac address="52:54:00:c0:59:8a"/>
      <source network="default"/>
      <model type="e1000e"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x01" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </interface>
    <serial type="pty">
      <target type="isa-serial" port="0">
        <model name="isa-serial"/>
      </target>
    </serial>
    <console type="pty">
      <target type="serial" port="0"/>
    </console>
    <channel type="spicevmc">
      <target type="virtio" name="com.redhat.spice.0"/>
      <address type="virtio-serial" controller="0" bus="0" port="1"/>
    </channel>
    <input type="tablet" bus="usb">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="1"/>
    </input>
    <input type="mouse" bus="ps2"/>
    <input type="keyboard" bus="ps2"/>
    <tpm model="tpm-crb">
      <backend type="emulator" version="2.0"/>
    </tpm>
    <graphics type="spice" autoport="yes">
      <listen type="address"/>
      <image compression="off"/>
    </graphics>
    <sound model="ich9">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x1b" function="0x0"/>
    </sound>
    <audio id="1" type="spice"/>
    <video>
      <model type="qxl" ram="65536" vram="65536" vgamem="16384" heads="1" primary="yes"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x0"/>
    </video>
    <hostdev mode="subsystem" type="usb" managed="yes">
      <source>
        <vendor id="0x046d"/>
        <product id="0xc07d"/>
      </source>
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="4"/>
    </hostdev>
    <hostdev mode="subsystem" type="usb" managed="yes">
      <source>
        <vendor id="0x046d"/>
        <product id="0xc33e"/>
      </source>
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="5"/>
    </hostdev>
    <hostdev mode="subsystem" type="usb" managed="yes">
      <source>
        <vendor id="0x1397"/>
        <product id="0x0507"/>
      </source>
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="6"/>
    </hostdev>
    <hostdev mode="subsystem" type="pci" managed="yes">
      <source>
        <address domain="0x0000" bus="0x09" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
      </source>
      <rom file="/usr/share/vgabios/vbios.rom"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x05" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </hostdev>
    <hostdev mode="subsystem" type="pci" managed="yes">
      <source>
        <address domain="0x0000" bus="0x09" slot="0x00" function="0x1"/>
      </source>
      <rom file="/usr/share/vgabios/vbios.rom"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x06" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </hostdev>
    <redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="2"/>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="3"/>
    </redirdev>
    <watchdog model="itco" action="reset"/>
    <memballoon model="virtio">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x04" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>

I hope this is the right place to post this and someone with more experience than me can help me find my issue

Finally got this to work myself. If anyone else ever runs into this problem, here's what worked for me:
First, i removed any and all hooks i installed previously by just completely deleting the /etc/libvirt/hooks folder
Follow this Guide from Step 1 through 6. DO NOT follow Step 7:
https://gitlab.com/risingprismtv/single-gpu-passthrough/-/wikis/home
(since i already had a VM installed, i just skipped step 5)
Next follow this Guide's automatic Install (Do not go to the manual branch. It seems outdated):
https://github.com/ilayna/Single-GPU-passthrough-amd-nvidia?tab=readme-ov-file
Next, go back to the Original Guides Step 8. You should remove the XML blocks as told by the guide (may need to enable XML editing) and also remove any other XML block if needed (Virt-manager may tell you that a specific function is not available without spice. Remove the blocks it talks about)
Next, add the <vendor_id state='on' value='123456789123'/> and <ioapic driver='kvm'/> lines as well as the <kvm> ... </kvm> block in the XML file as explained in Step 8b from the guide (I did not do the other things in that step)
Finally, i enabled topoext as explained in step 9 of the guide
This got me to be able to boot the VM with a fully passed through GPU (although it took another 10 minutes or so for windows to install the drivers and detect both monitors).

almost forgot, also add the <vendor_id state='on' value='123456789123'/> line in Step 8b, or nvidia will prevent the GPU from loading

Do you only have a single GPU? You would need a second GPU for the host unless you are connecting via SSH and have disabled the GUI. Also you probably need to isolate the GPU in the grub2 config so the host doesn't try to load it.
There is a good tutorial for 22.04 (which I think would be pretty similar to 24.04) here: https://mathiashueber.com/passthrough-windows-11-vm-ubuntu-22-04/

Hello, sorry for the late reply, busy week. Finally got this to work myself. You don't need a second GPU, you just cant use your host while the guest is running (and the setup is a lot more complicated).
